# What is the meaning of %2C in API links?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this API link, what is the meaning of '%2C'

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json
  ?fields=name%2Crating%2Cformatted_phone_number
  &place_id=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Reference: I want to create custom APIs from here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#maps_http_places_details_fields-txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%2C` is url encoded for `,`

[URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: Then for this particular API, is & and , same? Means if I want to ask multiple attributes, what should I use?